# What is the difference between two product-tables

Tags: html, css, woocommerce, tabular

Can't find difference between two tables in these two links:

https://producttable.barn2.co.uk/
and
https://producttable.barn2.co.uk/product-table-variations/

what is the difference between this:

[image]

.

.

and this:

[image]

why is it stacked horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: screenshot of the wider column version]

Checkout the screenshot. It looks like there is a width within the header  of the table column that holds those form fields in the version that does not wrap. The header cell has a larger width of 505px allowing more room for all the cells below it to contain the form items all in one line.

I hope this helps!